# Apply CSS to a li which contains a particular class on children/sub-children

Tags: html, css

How we can apply CSS to a li which contains a particular class on children/sub-children **with CSS only**. For example, we have

```html
<li>
  <div class='custom-class-1'>
    Alex
  </div>
</li>
<li>
  <div class='custom-class-2'>
    Alex
  </div>
</li>
```

So in this case, We want to apply a style to li which has a div with class custom-class-2, so in above example style will be applied on second li only.

Comment: you can't. You would need to select the aprent of a certain class and CSS has no parent selector. Your only chance is to skip that appraoch and use `nth-child` or `nth-of-type` unless you can manipulate the HTML markup and add a class directly.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has  Come back in a few years for this to be a thing.